# I need to setup a camera to follow a character in blend4web

Tags: constraints, blend4web, webgl

I'm working on a proof of concept for my comic companies website and want an immersive experience. To that end the goal is too put site visitors in the shoes of a character and have users "follow" the character in a click and point adventure.

(Until I can conceive of a free roaming control scheme that works for mobile and desktop)

I don't need a full third-person camera setup, though that would be ideal. I'd prefer to prototype with logic nodes of that's possible. Problem is not all constraints work in blend4web. Is there a work around that can get the prototype up and running that doesn't require me to dive into "The Joy of Coding" until after I make the proof of concept public?

Answer (score 0):

In b4w where is 3 predefined camera setups:

https://www.blend4web.com/doc/en/camera.html#hover-type-camera

You need to change camera type to hover

[image]